# prebuil apks not getting added in aosp build

Tags: android, android-source, android-tv, android.mk

I am trying to add a prebuilt apk to aosp source but the apk is not geting added.
Android.mk details is like

```
LOCAL_PATH := $(call my-dir)
include $(CLEAR_VARS)
LOCAL_MODULE_TAGS := optional
LOCAL_UNINSTALLABLE_MODULE := true
LOCAL_MODULE_PATH := $(TARGET_OUT_APPS)
LOCAL_MODULE := vlc-player
LOCAL_SRC_FILES := $(LOCAL_MODULE).apk
LOCAL_BUILT_MODULE_STEM := package.apk
LOCAL_MODULE_CLASS := APPS
LOCAL_MODULE_SUFFIX := $(COMMON_ANDROID_PACKAGE_SUFFIX)
LOCAL_CERTIFICATE := platform
LOCAL_MODULE_PATH := $(TARGET_OUT_DATA)
include $(BUILD_PREBUILT)
```

I have also added entry in core.mk under
PRODUCT_PACKAGES += 
vlc-player

but the apk is not added to the build

Answer (score 1):

Remove the flag `LOCAL_MODULE_TAGS := optional` and try calling the `PRODUCT_PACKAGES += vlc-player` in your device specific makefile, for example in

```
device/google/blueline/device.mk
```

Also manually verify the out directory by running a separate make call like , `make vlc` if your module is working.